# Test for COUNT()>X inside SQLite trigger

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

How can I compare the result of a COUNT inside a trigger in SQLite?

So far, this is the code I've come up with:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE WHEN 
        SELECT COUNT (*) FROM mytable >= 3
    THEN
        RAISE(FAIL, "Activated - mytrigger.")
    END;
END;
```

It fails to compile with:

```
Error: near "SELECT": syntax error
```

If I replace `SELECT COUNT (*) FROM mytable >= 3` with `1 == 1`, it compiles fine, and the trigger executes always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add parenthesis around the whole SELECT statement `SELECT COUNT (*) FROM mytable`

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE WHEN 
        (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM mytable) >= 3
    THEN
        RAISE(FAIL, "Activated - mytrigger.")
    END;
END;
```

Comment: I thought that SQLite doesn't support `IF..ELSE` statements, after reading this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294619/does-sqlite-supports-any-kind-of-ifcondition-statement-in-the-select

Comment: I tried it, but it failed with `Error: near "IF": syntax error`

Comment: Updated answer, I have removed the initial SELECT

Answer (score 2):

Try this code to delete last 50 row from table2 when count is greater than 100

```
CREATE **TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS** delete_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON table1 
  WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1) > 100
    BEGIN 
      delete From table1 where id not in (select id from table1 order by id desc limit 50; 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the count inside brackets:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE WHEN 
        SELECT (COUNT (*) FROM mytable) >= 3
    THEN
        RAISE(FAIL, "Activated - mytrigger.")
    END;
END;
```

Comment: SQLite, as I've written in the title and in the tags.

Comment: Yes, as is written at the end of my question, I tried with `1 == 1`.

Comment: Also, see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10834149/492336 - it seems that "PL/SQL syntax doesn't allow for including SQL statements in the IF clause", and also from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739444/declare-variable-in-sqlite-and-use-it it seems that SQLite doesn't support `DECLARE`, instead you have to use in-memory/temporary tables.

Comment: @twoleggedhorse just found the answer, so no need to try further.